# Disabling renewing session on Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, session, tomcat, tomcat5.5

How can I disable resetting session timeout in Tomcat 5.5 for particular requests? On a page I have a javascript function that periodically sends ajax calls to the server. On server side I don't want these calls to renew session lifetime.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since you didn't like my first idea, I came up with this JSP demonstration.
It's kind of a hack but it does work. To test, copy and paste. 
Browse to the first JSP. It will start a session and set the inactive interval.
After being redirected, keep hitting the Refresh button on your browser. 
No matter how times you request the second JSP, the current session will die.

test1.jsp

```
<%
   session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20); //for easy testing
   response.sendRedirect("test2.jsp");
%>
```

test2.jsp

```
<%@ page session="false" import="java.util.*" %>
<%
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  if(session == null){
                  out.print("Error, No Session!");
                  return;
  }
  long creationTime = session.getCreationTime();
  long now = new Date().getTime();
  long lastAccessedTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();
  int oldInterval = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
  int inactivePeriod = (int)(now - lastAccessedTime)/1000; 
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(oldInterval - inactivePeriod); 
  int newInterval = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
%>
<html>
<body>
session id is <%=session.getId()%>
<br/><%=creationTime%> = creationTime
<br/><%=lastAccessedTime%> = lastAccessedTime
<br/><%=now%> = now
<br/><%=oldInterval%> = oldInterval in seconds 
<br/><%=inactivePeriod%> = inactivePeriod
<br/><%=newInterval%> = newInterval in seconds 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks (+1), it looks like it may work. I will wait for a while to see if there is any other answers...

Comment: I don't see any easier way on Tomcat. You would need to make some quite invasive changes to Tomcat's internals to allow a request to access a session object without updating the last accessed time.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate web app(along side your present one) to take the AJAX calls. 
In this second web app, you can avoid creating sessions. You can do this by using session="false" in the page diective of your JSP or by just not creating one explicitly in a Servlet. If you need to share data between these two apps then you can use the attribute crossContext="true"  in your Context definition. 
[Tomcat Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not an option for me (at least at the moment). I have to work with quite old system, and refactoring may take too long. Also, I need session data in the handler, I just don't want to renew session (if session expires, handler returns different result)

Comment: So, you just want to write code for the AJAX handler ? Nothing else ?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that the handler should have access to session data without prolonging session lifetime